# All my forms submit to the same script

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm programming a webpage and in my index, I have two forms.

The 1st is for the login:

`<form method="post" action="login.php">...</form>`

The 2nd is for search:

`<form method="post" action="search.php">...</form>`

My problem is that when I submit the search form, it works as if the `action` is targeting `login.php`. When I see the source code, the tag `<form method="post" action="search.php">` doesn't appear.

Comment: Sure that you're closed the form-tags with `</form>` properly?

Comment: Did you synchronize your editor with your test server correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most probable cause of the problem is incorrectly nested forms or missing closing form for login form. Check the generated HTML for the validity of the HTML and if not post the generated HTML so that we can help you debug.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell without seeing the complete page, but I would guess that you have one form inside the other — which is forbidden. You cannot nest forms.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I didn't really close the form tags, I typed `<form>` instead of `</form>`. Sorry.